# Flutter: How to restore or download sqlite database from google drive

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, google-drive-api

I am developing a Flutter application that uses an SQLite database. The user can take a backup of the database and save it to Google Drive, which works fine. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to restore the backup. I have tried many ways, but I have failed each time.

```dart
Future<void> _downloadFile(String fileName, String fileId) async {
    final googleSignIn = sign_in.GoogleSignIn.standard(scopes: [drive.DriveApi.driveScope]);
    final sign_in.GoogleSignInAccount? account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final authheader = await account?.authHeaders;

    var client = GoogleAuthClient(authheader!);
    var driveFile = drive.DriveApi(client);

    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    var dbPath = p.join(databasesPath, 'my_database.db');
    
    // I'm not sure what to do next. I need to retrieve the file from Google Drive and replace it with my_database.db.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me, except if I have view in database it won't affect until I restart the app, unless I download it the file to local device and the restore it.
try to find away that let you download the db as a file to your local device. So use this code until then.

```
  Future<void> _downloadFile(String fileName, String fileId) async {
    final googleSignIn =
        sign_in.GoogleSignIn.standard(scopes: [drive.DriveApi.driveScope]);
    final sign_in.GoogleSignInAccount? account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final authheader = await account?.authHeaders;

    var client = GoogleAuthClient(authheader!);
    var driveFile = drive.DriveApi(client);

    //here you go:::::::::::::::::

    var result = (await driveFile.files
        .get(fileId, downloadOptions: drive.DownloadOptions.fullMedia)) ;
    if (result is! drive.Media) throw Exception("invalid response");
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    var dbPath = p.join(databasesPath, 'my_database.db');
    final saveFile = File(dbPath);
    print('dbPath $dbPath');
    List<int> dataStore = [];
    result.stream.listen((event) {
      print('data received : ${event.length}');
      dataStore.insertAll(dataStore.length, event);
    }, onDone: () {
      print('task done');
      saveFile.writeAsBytes(dataStore);
      print("File saved at ${saveFile.path}");
    }, onError: (error) {
      print("Some Error");
    });
  }
```

***Edit*** I have found a way to download the file and then copy it to database path, its actually same above code but with little Changs:

```
  Future<void> _downloadFile(String fileName, String fileId) async {
    final googleSignIn =
        sign_in.GoogleSignIn.standard(scopes: [drive.DriveApi.driveScope]);
    final sign_in.GoogleSignInAccount? account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final authheader = await account?.authHeaders;

var client = GoogleAuthClient(authheader!);
    var driveFile = drive.DriveApi(client);

    var result = (await driveFile.files
        .get(fileId, downloadOptions: drive.DownloadOptions.fullMedia));
    if (result is! drive.Media) throw Exception("invalid response");
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    var dbPath = p.join(databasesPath, 'my_database.db');
    print('dbPath $dbPath');

    Directory copyTo = Directory(createAppFolders.dbAppDir!);
    print('copyTo: $copyTo');
    File newPath = File("${copyTo.path}/my_database.db");

    final saveFile = newPath;

    List<int> dataStore = [];
    result.stream.listen((event) {
      print('data received : ${event.length}');
      dataStore.insertAll(dataStore.length, event);
    }, onDone: () async {
      await saveFile.writeAsBytes(dataStore).then((value) => newPath.copy(dbPath));
      print('task done');
      print("File saved at ${saveFile.path}");
    }, onError: (error) {
      print("Some Error");
    });
  }
```